# HG Workbench working directory over ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, mercurial

I manage a team of developers who are editing files on a headless development server via SFTP. We use Mercurial (HG) to version the files. It's my job to make sure the team is doing the correct things, so I need to be able to do `hg status` and `hg diff` and so forth. Up to now I've been doing this over SSH on the command line, but I would like to be able to use HG Workbench, or something like it, over SSH. Something to send the needed commands over SSH, parse the response, and display the results. I believe this is how Workbench works anyways, but only on the local machine, and I don't see any option to do it remotely.

Is there any workaround way to do this, or another program that can do what I'm trying to do with Workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have ended up doing is using the PHPStorm IDE to do this for me. It is able to sync the working directory with the remote server, including the `.hg` files, and I can then see the differences in an easy way, as well as do commits right from the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Clone the mercurial repository to your local machine and then run [tortoise hg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) on your local machine.  When you do a push of any modifications they will be synced onto the remote machine - *it is a distributed VCS after all*.
2. On the remote machine type `hg serve` and it will run up a web server.  You can then connect to the web server with a browser and perform the operations that you need via the web interface.

Comment: Pulling and pushing requires commits if I'm not mistaken, which is what I want to avoid doing until I can be sure the work is satisfactory. I will try out the `hg serve` option in the next couple of days and let you know, thanks for the response!

Comment: If you pull to your local machine you will get the changes and then any operations that you do on your local machine will start from a exact duplicate of the server, i.e. a clone.  Any changes will require commits, just as they would on the remote machine, and a push will put the remote repository to the same state - the good news is that if you make a mistake and realise before you push you can just delete the local directory, take a fresh clone and start again.